# The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator while renaming site column

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, list-view-threshold

I am getting

> The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view
>   threshold enforced by the administrator

while renaming site column in SharePoint online using csom. I have faced this issue in the past while fetching items from the large list but this is a different scenario, here I am just trying to rename the site column. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the code

```
var siteColumnField = rootWeb.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle(ColumnInternalName);
siteColumnField.Title = "UpdatedName";
siteColumnField.UpdateAndPushChanges(true);                    
this.clientContext.ExecuteQueryRetry(ConfigHelper.ThrottleRetryCount, ConfigHelper.ThrottleDelay);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are running an operation against a column. If it is used in a large list, this can trigger the LVT exception, since it will modify the list and all items in it.

You can prevent this if you decide not to push these changed down to child content types. Since this is SPO, you have not really many options to bypass this error. The only option would be to bring down the large list below 5000 items, or not update the large list.

Comment: Here I am able to rename the column at list/library level using user interface which is having more than 50k items. So, can I do the same using CSOM? If yes, then I won't push the changes from site column instead I will rename at list/library level.

Comment: Mind adding the code you use to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach is used to cater to this problem using indexed columns. If you use the index column SharePoint does not need to iterate the entire list to deliver the results. When you are viewing or querying (CAML, ODATA, and REST) against the list SharePoint will process the entire set of items to get the required results even though you have mentioned limits or filters unless it is indexed.

For more information , please check [Manage large lists and libraries in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) .

Comment: I am not querying anything from the list/library, I am just renaming the site column and pushing those changes to list/libraries where that column is used. Still, I am getting this error in the customer environment. I have tried to replicate the issue in the development environment and created one library with more than 20k records and I am able to rename the site column and the library with 20k  records getting updated with the new name.